# Creating Correlation table with the Target variable in Python

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I am trying to create correation table with `Target` variable but currently I am facing an issue.

I just want the list of the top 10 variables correlated to my variable `Delay_Days`

I am getting top 10 correlated variables

**My code**

```
def mosthighlycorrelated(mydataframe, numtoreport):
    # find the correlations
    cormatrix = data_clean.corr()
    # set the correlations on the diagonal or lower triangle to zero,
    # so they will not be reported as the highest ones:
    cormatrix *= np.tri(*cormatrix.values.shape, k=-1).T
    # find the top n correlations
    cormatrix = cormatrix.stack()
    cormatrix = cormatrix.reindex(cormatrix.abs().sort_values(ascending=False).index).reset_index()
    # assign human-friendly names
    cormatrix.columns = ["FirstVariable", "SecondVariable", "Correlation"]
    return cormatrix.head(numtoreport)

mosthighlycorrelated(data_clean['Delay_Days'], 10)
```

This not working as expected. How to fix this.

```
 **Current Ouput**
First Variable  Second Variable Correlation
A                 B              0.9
C                 G              0.85
B                 D              0.7
A                 F             0.65

    **Expected Output** 
First Variable  Second Variable Correlation
A                  B             0.9
A                  F             0.7
A                  C             0.3
A                  D             0.2
A                  E              0.1
```

Comment: Could you put the output example?

Comment: @jalazbe, updated with the output example

Comment: Try doing `cormatrix.sort_values(by='Correlation', ascending=True'` before doing `return cormatrix.head(numtoreport)`